Transfer erc20 tokens ethers-v6
I was using token contract to transfer erc20 tokens to an address and it was working perfectly fine. but since i have migrated to ethers v6. everything has messed up. All the methods are either replaced or renamed.
const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, erc20Abi, ether)
const decimals = await contract.decimals()
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(fromPrivateKey, ether);
const amount = ethers.parseUnits(quantity.toString(), decimals);
const contractSigner = contract.connect(signer)
const gasFee = await contractSigner.estimateGas.transfer(to, amount)
const gasLimit = gasFee.toNumber()

const tx = await contractSigner.transfer(to, amount, {
  gasPrice: enhancePrice,
  gasLimit: gasLimit,
});
return tx.hash;

both of these lines
const gasFee = await contractSigner.estimateGas.transfer(to, amount)


const tx = await contractSigner.transfer(to, amount, {
  gasPrice: enhancePrice,
  gasLimit: gasLimit,
});

are now giving error that neither property transfer or nor estimateGas exists on contractSigner. i have checked the migration list as well can't seem to find anything there as well
Ethers v6 migration docs
Can someone help?

In ethers.js v6, estimateGas() should be called like this:
const estimatedGas = await contractSigner.functionName.estimateGas(arg1, arg2, ...);

The revised portion of the code would be:
const gasFee = await contractSigner.transfer.estimateGas(to, amount);
const gasLimit = parseInt(gasFee)
console.log(gasLimit)

const tx = await contractSigner.transfer(to, amount, {
    gasLimit: gasLimit,
});

const receipt = await tx.wait();

console.log(receipt.hash)


like i mentioned in my question that contractSigner neither recognizes transfer property not estimateGas so
contractSigner.transfer.estimateGas(to, amount)
is not working nor is
const tx = await contractSigner.transfer(to, amount, {
gasLimit: gasLimit,
});

In your question, you were using contractSigner.estimateGas.transfer. Please try using contractSigner.transfer.estimateGas.

Also, make sure that you’re using the correct ABI while creating the contract instance.
